# "Some Error Occurred" in PayuMoney Integration in Android

Tags: android, hash, integration, payumoney

I'm trying to integrate Payumoney in Android, but always getting error of

> some error occurred

Below is code.

hashcal:

```
public static String hashCal(String hashString) {
        StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder();
        MessageDigest messageDigest = null;
        try {
            messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
            messageDigest.update(hashString.getBytes());
            byte[] mdbytes = messageDigest.digest();
            for (byte hashByte : mdbytes) {
                hash.append(Integer.toString((hashByte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hash.toString();
    }
```

Main Code:

```
 Random rand = new Random();
                String randomString = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt()) + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
                String txnId = hashCal(randomString).substring(0, 20);

                int amount = new BigDecimal(100).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP).intValue();

                String hashSequence = "mLeqrgMpR|"+txnId+"|"+amount+"|Coupons|abcdef|test@gmail.com|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|3d7vtDalxm";

                String hash = hashCal(hashSequence);

                PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam.Builder builder = new
                        PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam.Builder();
                builder.setAmount(amount)                          // Payment amount
                        .setTxnId(txnId)                                             // Transaction ID
                        .setPhone("+911234567890")                                           // User Phone number
                        .setProductName("Coupons")                   // Product Name or description
                        .setFirstName("abcdef")                              // User First name
                        .setEmail("test@gmail.com")                                            // User Email ID
                        .setsUrl("https://test.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php")                    // Success URL (surl)
                        .setfUrl("https://test.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php")
                        .setIsDebug(true)                              // Integration environment - true (Debug)/ false(Production)
                        .setKey("mLeqrgMpR")                        // Merchant key
                        .setMerchantId("12359971");             // Merchant ID

                PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam paymentParam = builder.build();
                //set the hash
                paymentParam.setMerchantHash(hash);

                PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(paymentParam, getActivity(), R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar,false);
```

Whenever I try to execute above code, payumoney's activity get finishes and throws the toast "some error occurred".

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the debug credentials of `MerchantID` and `MerchantKey`?

Comment: yes, but my debug and production credentials are same, is this a problem?

Comment: That can't be possible, mail PayUMoney from your registered email id asking for debug credentials.

Comment: I've sent them, but I've tried live mode as well as test mode with those credentials but getting the same error.

Comment: @PranavFulkari you solved this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. how to fix it??

Comment: yes, you need server-side code for it.

Comment: how to fix it??

Comment: @PranavFulkari ... Can you please explain what is to be done at the server side ... because in my case iOS app is running fine but the android app gets this error.